# Dynamic text Colour on DateTimePicker UserControl - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, datetimepicker

I am creating a windows user control based on a DateTimePicker.  The control is set to show just the time so it displays thus:

[image: DateTimePicker time only]

I have a public property TimeIsValid:

```
public bool TimeIsValid
{
   get { return _timeIsValid; }
   set
   {
      _timeIsValid = value;
      Refresh();
   }
}
```

and when this is set to false I want the text to turn red.  So I have overridden the OnPaint with the following code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
     {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, 
        _timeIsValid ? new SolidBrush(Color.Black) : new SolidBrush(Color.Red),
        ClientRectangle);

     }
```

This did nothing.  So in the in the constructor I have added the following code:

```
public DateTimePicker(IContainer container)
{
    container.Add(this);
    InitializeComponent();
    //code below added
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
}
```

Which works, kind of, but causes some alarming results i.e.

- The control does not appear selected even when it is.
- Clicking on the up/down controls changes the underlying value of the control but does not always change the visible value.
- The control does not repaint properly when changing its value via another control but moving a mouse over the control seems to force the repaint.

Look at this weirdness for instance ...

[image: Partially repainted control]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lousy control to try to inherit from, but some things to try:

Add the double-buffer:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
              ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

Clear the background and draw the highlight if the control has the focus:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
  Color textColor = Color.Red;
  if (this.Focused) {
    textColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, 
                             new Rectangle(4, 4, this.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - 8, this.ClientSize.Height - 8));
  }
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, textColor, Color.Empty, TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

and invalidate the control when the value changes:

```
protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs) {
  base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
  this.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Most excellent - many thanks.  The only issue I have now is that you cannot identify whether hours or minutes are selected.  Both are highlighted when you select the control.

Comment: Where do you have to add that 'double buffer' -- what is "this" in that first snippet of code?

Comment: @EastofNowhere Since the question was about inheriting from the DateTimePicker control, `this` references that control.  Example: `public class MyControl : DateTimePicker {}`.  You then set the styles in the constructor of the class: `public MyControl() {...}`